# Get select list Value in node template

Tags: theming, nodes, 8

I have a integer selection list field in my content types with some `key|Value` options.

```
0|CEO
1|CTO
2|Manager
```

now in my template  I want get value. I try `{{node.field_positon.value}}` but it return me `key` value (it return 0 or 1 or 2 ).

**My question is** how can I get value of selection option in template file?

**notice:** I know I can paly with `content.field_position` ( but it put some markup wrappers around field),**I want get it** by `node` variable.

Comment: Comments have been removed. Please don't use them for extended discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the following, and you will obtain what you want to achieve.

```
{{ content.field_position[0]['#markup'] }}
```

Comment: Although I think maybe there is better solution in future but It solved my problem, thank you for attention and spend time to find a solution.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

To get the raw value use:

```
{{ content.field_position.0 }}
```